# Observer Event Not firing

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I created a custom extension that should fire when a purchase is successful but the Observer function is not working. Below is my config file and Model

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
        <Net_Saver>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Net_Saver>
        </modules>
        <global>
        <helpers>
            <saver>
                <class>Net_Saver_Helper</class>
            </saver>
        </helpers>
        </global>
        <models>
            <net_saver>
            <class>Net_Saver_Model</class>
            </net_saver>
        </models>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <observers>
            <net_saver>
            <class>net_saver/observer</class>
            <method>sendOrder</method>
            </net_saver>
        </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>

</config>
```

Here's the Model

```
class Net_Saver_Model_Observer
{

    public function sendOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       //details removed
     }
}
```

Anyone know what i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closing `</global>` tag is not correctly placed in your `config.xml` file, move it to the end of the file, right before `</config>` closing tag

Fix that, the rest of the code seems to be ok